# Why does using a (long long) cast in this code change the result?

Tags: c++, casting

I wrote these code for the question in link https://www.codechef.com/JAN16/problems/RGAME

code 1>>

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
long long int t[100001],i,MOD=1000000007;
t[0]=1;
for(i=1;i<100001;i++){
    t[i]=(t[i-1]*2)%MOD;
    //cout<<t[i]<<endl;
}
int test;
cin>>test;
long long int n,a[100001];
while(test--){
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    long long int j=(2*a[0])%MOD;
    long long int s=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        int x = (j * ((a[i] * t[n - i]) % MOD)) % MOD;
        s = (s+ x) % MOD;
        j = (j + (a[i] * t[i]) % MOD) % MOD;
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

code 2>>

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
long long int t[100001],i,MOD=1000000007;
t[0]=1;
for(i=1;i<100001;i++){
    t[i]=(t[i-1]*2)%MOD;
    //cout<<t[i]<<endl;
}
int test;
cin>>test;
long long int n,a[100001];
while(test--){
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    long long int j=(2*a[0])%MOD;
    long long int s=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        int x = ((long long)(j) * (((long long)(a[i]) * t[n - i]) % MOD)) % MOD;
        s = (s+ x) % MOD;
        j = (j + ((long long)(a[i]) * t[i]) % MOD) % MOD;
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

It can be seen that in code 1 I haven't type-casted variables j and a[i] while calculations in for loop, although they are declared as long long. and in code 2, I've used typecasting.
As per my knowledge, there is no difference between both codes. But while submitting I got wrong answer for code 1 and accepted for code 2. So it seems to me that type-casting done within for loop is quit necessary, can anybody tell me why so?

Comment: You are probably hitting Undefined Behaviour. Your stack variables `t` and `a` are too big and are likely overflowing the stack.

Comment: The use of `using namespace std;` guarantees this is not C.  Should just use C++ tag, and remove C.

Comment: Why on earth are you including `<bits/stdc++.h>`? Everything under `bits` are libstdc++ internals, inherently nonportable, subject to change and which shouldn't be included directly.

Comment: What compiler?  Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit?  Is your platform LP64 or LLP64?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I think LP64 or LLP64 isn't important because the code only uses `long long` and `int` which are 64 and 32 bits respectively on both systems

Comment: My point is that there's not enough information here to even try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
int x = (((a[i] * t[n - i]) % MOD) * j) % MOD;
s = (s + x) % MOD;
j = ((a[i] * t[i]) % MOD + j) % MOD;
```

if you want to add two different values, put the longer one first...

EDIT:

if s + x > 2^^31 - 1, another type conversion is required:

```
s = (1LL * s + x) % MOD;
```

Comment: Would you please go into some detail about why your code changes the behavior?